# SQL trying to make a ranking column based on age group out of age column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server

so i have this table

```
CREATE TABLE RaceResult(name char, time int, age int);
INSERT INTO RaceResult (name, time, age) VALUES
('Steve', '12', '33'),
('Tim', '34', '28'),
('Mark', '22', '37'),
('Tom', '21', '30'),
('Cliff', '13', '33'),
('Vini', '17', '28'),
('Matt', '10', '28'),
('Ben', '9', '29'),
('Brandon', '15', '14');
```

and i want to create a 4th column that it ranks them 1st 2nd 3rd etc based on their age group

The age groups are

- 0 - 15 yrs
- 16 - 29 yrs
- 30+ yrs

my select statement so far is:

```
SELECT
CASE 
    WHEN age < '16' and  age > 0  
       THEN 'group1' 
    WHEN age < '30' and  age > 15  
       THEN 'group2' 
    WHEN age > '29'  
       THEN 'group3' 
       ELSE 0 
END as rank, *
FROM RaceResult
ORDER BY time
```

but instead of the rank column to just say 'group 1, 2 or 3' i  want it to output like:

```
            RESULTS
Name    Time    Age     Rank
=====   ====    ===     ====
Ben      9      29      1
Matt    10      28      2
Steve   12      33      1
Cliff   13      33      2
Brandon 15      14      1
Vini    17      28      3
Tom     21      30      3
Mark    22      37      4
Tim     34      28      4
```

really appreciate if anyone could point me in the right direction

Comment: Your desired output does not correlate with your description of groups. Also, what DBMS you are using - SQL Server or MySQL?

Comment: sql i believe, im using w3s sql tryit editor to test it out

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT NAME,
                time,
                age,
                CASE
                  WHEN ( age / 15 ) + 1 < 3 THEN ( age / 15 ) + 1
                  ELSE 3
                END AS [group]
         FROM   RaceResult)
SELECT NAME,time,age,
       Row_number() OVER (partition BY [group] ORDER BY time ) [Rank]          
FROM   cte
ORDER  BY time
```

Comment: @user2792314 Tim's age is 28 then how he got the rank 4

Comment: @user2792314 - Got the logic

Comment: @user2792314 - check now

Comment: @user2792314 - I think now it is fine check the answer. Intially i ordered by age thats the mistake it should be time. You need to mention all these in the question if ask your questions clearly with 15 mins you will get the answers from SO.

Answer (score 1):

This query should do what you want:

```
SELECT
  age_group.*,
  @num := if (@age_group = age_group, @num + 1, 1) rank,
  @age_group := age_group as dummy
  FROM (
     SELECT
         RaceResult.*,
         @group := CASE 
                     WHEN age < '16' and  age > 0
                         THEN 'group1'
                     WHEN age < '30' and  age > 15
                         THEN 'group2'
                     WHEN age > '29'
                         THEN 'group3'
                     ELSE 0
                   END as age_group 
     FROM RaceResult,
     (select @age_group = '', @num = 1) init
     ORDER BY age_group, time
  ) age_group
```

The solution is based on info from this link:

http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/02/how-to-number-rows-in-mysql/